# Suitescript Error - RCRD_HAS_BEEN_CHANGED - Closing Sales Order after transform to Invoice

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I have a recurring error in my code (RCRD_HAS_BEEN_CHANGED). At the high level the script looks at recently fulfilled sales orders and invoices them. It then iterates over all lines of the invoice and changes to the quantity fulfilled. I then want to go through each line of the sales order and close it out. All my code works without error until I implement the SO 'closing' section and then when trying to save the sales order return the RCRD_HAS_BEEN_CHANGED error.

I know that this error doesnt have anything to do with users accessing the sales order in the UI at the same time the code is running. And there are no other custom scripts running in the background that would interact with this script.
I believe the issue is that this script itself is accessing the sales order concurrently. I have tried placing the 'closing' block of code in different places in the script with little help. Independently of the other parts of the script the closing of sales orders works fine.

```
    var salesOrderIds = [];
            for(var i = 0; i < itemFulfillmentList.length; i++){
                var currentOrder = itemFulfillmentList[i].getValue(searchResults.columns[1]);

                salesOrderIds.push(currentOrder);
            }

            log.debug ({ 
                    title: 'sales order list',
                    details: salesOrderIds
            });

                    .....       
            //transform the resulting sales orders into an invoice, iterating one by one

            for(var i = 0; i < salesOrderIds.length; i++) {


                var currentSalesOrder = record.load ({
                    type: record.Type.SALES_ORDER, 
                    id: salesOrderIds[i],
                    isDynamic: false
                });

                var newInvoice = record.transform({
                    fromType: record.Type.SALES_ORDER,
                    fromId: salesOrderIds[i],
                    toType: record.Type.INVOICE,
                });
```

.....
//outside for loop that when the invoice is saved closes out each line of the sales order

```
    for(var m = 0; m < salesOrderIds.length; m++){
                var salesOrderId = salesOrderIds[m];
                var salesOrder = record.load ({
                    type: record.Type.SALES_ORDER, 
                    id: salesOrderId,
                    isDynamic: false
                });
                var salesOrderLineCountClosure = salesOrder.getLineCount({
                    sublistId: 'item',
                });
                for(var n = 0; n < salesOrderLineCountClosure; n++) {
                    var salesOrderClosure = salesOrder.setSublistValue ({
                        sublistId: 'item',
                        fieldId: 'isclosed',
                        line: n,
                        value: true
                    });

                    log.debug ({ 
                        title: 'SO line closure'+n,
                        details: salesOrderClosure
                    }); 

                    salesOrder.save({
                        enableSourcing: false,
                        ignoreMandatoryFields: false
                    });

                }
            }
```

Comment: What type of script is this? Can you show the entry point function(s)?

Answer (score 0):

You have two instances where you load the sales order. Here

```
     var currentSalesOrder = record.load ({
         type: record.Type.SALES_ORDER, 
         id: salesOrderIds[i],
         isDynamic: false
     });
```

And here

```
            var salesOrder = record.load ({
                type: record.Type.SALES_ORDER, 
                id: salesOrderId,
                isDynamic: false
            });
```

It could be that you are loading the same record twice then when you try to save it, the system throws an error.